# cURL error 60: See http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html

Tags: php, rest, google-plus

I am trying to fetch profile data using the google+ rest API but I'm getting this error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'GuzzleHttp\Ring\Exception\RingException' with message 'cURL error 60: See [http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html'](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html%27) in C:\wamp\www\plus3\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Exception\RequestException.php on line 51

Here is the error Screen shot:

[image: Here]

Currently I'm working on localhost. I have tried everything which includes
installing composer, curl... etc.
Not sure what is it that I'm doing wrong; why can't I fetch data from profile?

Here is the code:

```
<?php

include_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
include_once "templates/base.php";

  session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();


  $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("Google+ PHP Starter Application");

    // credentials are intentionally not disclosed but they are correct. 
     $client->setClientId('XXXXXX');
     $client->setClientSecret('XXXXXXX');
     $client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/....');
     $client->setDeveloperKey('XXXXX');

    $plus = new Google_Service_Plus($client);

//Everything works fine before this line...as soon as i write the line
//below to fetch results with name brett...it throws me an error.

    $results = $plus->people->search('brett');
   
    ?>
  <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head><link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' /></head>
    <body>
    <header><h1>Google+ Sample App</h1></header>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Did you look at the error?

Comment: I did...i think its related to curl...i did installed it...is there anyway i can double check ?

Answer (score 0):

A little late maybe, but for anyone strolling around these pages in the future:

Check your php.ini file for the option 'curl.cainfo'. Specify the absolute path to the certificate (which you can download at: http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem).
Activate the option by removing the semicolon at the start of the line. Reboot the Apache server and you should be fine.

Comment: Hi, Can you tell me how can i install it on my homestead

Comment: Hi Tuhin, unfortunatelly I'm not familiar with Homestead. Having said that; my answer did not involve "installing" anything. Just activating an option that was deactivated by default. Good luck anyway!

Answer (score 0):

If your operating system has centos or a Fedora, must allowed Httpd_can_network_connect connection.
by default all access httpd(nginx-apache-...) are disable.

```
setsebool httpd_can_network_connect 1
```