# GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException cURL error 3: (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) when installing laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel

I'm just installing a laravel app in my ubuntu 20.4 with php.4 / mysql

Everything is working, laravel installation, composer, migrations, seeding, php artisan serve.

But when I try to access: http://localhost:8000, I get:

```
GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException cURL error 3: (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

I already tried:

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
```

What should I do ?

Comment: Do you have a base url set? In your .env or config?

Comment: `APP_URL=http://localhost:8000`

Comment: Try to change it to: `http://localhost`

Comment: changed it but same error

Comment: Restart the localhost too. And if you have it cached, run `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: already did it, added to the question. Also did: `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: already restart `php artisan serve`

Comment: @Juliatzin And this is a fresh Laravel install with no custom code or config yet?

Comment: @KurtFriars yep, a fresh laravel install works ! In this project, I use laravel nova, but I am just cloning my working project in another computer

Answer (score 0):

For quick solution you can disable SSL verify for Guzzle when you using local environment. Check your link for existing too.

If you have this problem on real server you can try another way you can download `cacert.pem` file from http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem (see [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34696406/curl-error-60-see-http-curl-haxx-se-libcurl-c-libcurl-errors-html)) and set this file for guzzle. Example below

```
$guzzle = new \Guzzle\Http\Client();
$guzzle->setDefaultOption('verify', '/path/to/cacert.pem');
```

If you get this error on server please, contact to support. This is problem with server configuration and all solutions above is "quick fix"